# Extend a QT QRadioButton Class to attach QSound::Play to a private slot

Tags: qt, class, subclass, slots, qradiobutton

I've been playing around with QT5 for Android, I've been struggling a bit with extending an existing class so I can play a sound anytime I click on a radio button that has been promoted.

I'm using the standard QT APP template to get started,

This is what I have so far:
radiowclick.h:

```
#ifndef RADIOWCLICK_H
#define RADIOWCLICK_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <qradiobutton.h>
class RadioWClick : public QRadioButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
Public:
    RadioWClick(QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:
    void clicked();
private slots:
    void PrivateClicked();
};
#endif // RADIOWCLICK_H
```

radiowclick.cpp:

```
#include "radiowclick.h"
#include <QtMultimedia/qsound.h>
RadioWClick::RadioWClick(QWidget *parent) :
    QRadioButton(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PrivateClicked()));
}

void RadioWClick::PrivateClicked()
{
    QSound::play(":/sounds/ButtonClick.wav");
}
```

main.cpp:
    #include "radiowclick.h"...

Everything compiles fine, when I use vanilla sockets and slots I get the clicking sound, but with the promoted radiobuttons and the private slot i have no joy.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No joy means the slot is called, but the sound is not playing, or something else? Are you putting that sound file into resource?

Comment: Whoever voted me down a little feedback would be appreciated.  I'd been researching and tried different approaches for hours, I only asked the question as a last resort and this seems to be a question that would be useful to others.

Comment: The sound file is in the resource file, as I mentioned in my original post when I use the normal QRadioButton class and include the 
    QSound::play...
for each signal i have no problems, only when i try creating a subclass am i having issues.

Comment: Did you change the code here after the answer was given? That's not good practice. We can't see what the mistake was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is you're overwriting the `connect` signal defined in `QAbstractButton` which is a base of `QPushButton`.

Try removing your definition of `clicked()` and connecting your signal `PrivateClicked()` to the base class `clicked()` signal.

Some code:

```
class RadioWClick : public QRadioButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
Public:
    RadioWClick(QWidget *parent = 0);    
private slots:
    void PrivateClicked();
};
```

And the implementation

```
RadioWClick::RadioWClick(QWidget *parent) :
    QRadioButton(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PrivateClicked()));
}

void RadioWClick::PrivateClicked()
{
    QSound::play(":/sounds/ButtonClick.wav");
}
```

NOTE: I have not tested this code. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I would vote you up but i don't have enough reputation.  I haven't had a chance to test your solution but it makes a lot of sense.

Thanks for taking the time to write a reply and I will let you know how it goes when I get home. If it works you'll be my favorite person of the day!

Comment: **Thankyou!!  I can't believe i was so close to it all along!  thanks again!**

Comment: @user2342062 You're welcome. Glad the solution worked for you.